# Redefine a weak IRQ handler using linker directives/macros or any other trick

Tags: c, linker, arm, microcontroller

Environment - KEIL ARMcc v5.05 compiler, ARMlink v5.05 linker for LPC1769

I asked this question on some other forums too, if this looks familiar.
I want to create a base project which can be reused for same or similar
processors.I am trying to create interrupt handlers which can be defined/declared by a macro and can over-ride the default weak definition.

For. e.g I want to write DBG port handler but I want the next person to
chose what UART he wants by just changing a macro in a  header file.

/* The following macro will create text void UART0_IRQhandler */

`#define DBG_UART UART0
 #define MAKE_IRQH(x) void x##_IRQHandler(void)
 #define IRQH(x) MAKE_IRQH(x)`

So in my dbg.c file I write

```
IRQH(DBG_UART){
/*....... UART handling stuff ....*/ 
}
```

My intention is that next person can take this project and just change say
UART0 to UART1 and won't need to change dbg.c file.

The above thing doesn't work, and my code still hits default weak handler as
though void UART0_IRQhandler has not been defined.
Do you guys see any other way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

I was using same UART in different places, mistake on my part. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

When designing macros, you might want to look at the preprocessors output, e.g. with `gcc -E`.

Then you could have spotted the error:

`#define IRQH() MAKE_IRQH(x)`

shoud actually be:
`#define IRQH(x) MAKE_IRQH(x)`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo while trying to make post look pretty. I am using Keil's editor which does dynamic syntax checking, and macro expansion is correct.